# How to access command line arguments of the caller inside a function?

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments, argv

I'm attempting to write a function in bash that will access the scripts command line arguments, but they are replaced with the positional arguments to the function. Is there any way for the function to access the command line arguments if they aren't passed in explicitly?

```
# Demo function
function stuff {
  echo $0 $*
}

# Echo's the name of the script, but no command line arguments
stuff

# Echo's everything I want, but trying to avoid
stuff $*
```

Comment: I am kind of confused , you want the args with out passing them?

Comment: Yes, the point is to get too the command line arguments from inside a function without passing them in as functional arguments.

It has to do with an error handling situation in which I want to do error handling based on command line arguments independently of the arguments passed into the function.

Comment: FYI, `$*` is extremely buggy -- it'll change `./yourScript "first argument" "second argument"` to `./yourscript "first" "argument" "second" "argument"`, or change `./yourscript '*.txt'` to something like `./yourscript one.txt two.txt` despite the quotes.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

My reading of the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html) says this stuff is captured in [BASH_ARGV](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-BASH_005fARGV),
although it talks about "the stack" a lot.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extdebug

function argv {
  for a in ${BASH_ARGV[*]} ; do
    echo -n "$a "
  done
  echo
}

function f {
  echo f $1 $2 $3
  echo -n f ; argv
}

function g {
  echo g $1 $2 $3
  echo -n g; argv
  f
}

f boo bar baz
g goo gar gaz
```

Save in `f.sh`

```
$ ./f.sh arg0 arg1 arg2
f boo bar baz
fbaz bar boo arg2 arg1 arg0
g goo gar gaz
ggaz gar goo arg2 arg1 arg0
f
fgaz gar goo arg2 arg1 arg0
```

Comment: Do note that itterating the array like that causes the args to be in reverse order from the command line.

Comment: `${BASH_ARGV[*]}` should arguably be `"${BASH_ARGV[@]}"` with double quotes and `@`

Comment: `BASH_ARGV` is not only in reverse order. In addition if it is accessed in a `source`'d script it contains the path of the sourced script as argument, too. Because of that I finally deviced to copy the script arguments to a new array like `export SCRIPT_ARG=("${@}")` and use this in a function.

Answer (score 118):

If you want to have your arguments C style (array of arguments + number of arguments) you can use `$@` and `$#`.

`$#` gives you the number of arguments.
`$@` gives you all arguments. You can turn this into an array by `args=("$@")`.

So for example:

```
args=("$@")
echo $# arguments passed
echo ${args[0]} ${args[1]} ${args[2]}
```

Note that here `${args[0]}` actually is the 1st argument and not the name of your script.

Comment: This doesn't address the question - it's asking about passing the command-line arguments along to a shell function.

Comment: @Jefromi, actually, it answers the question perfectly. You can use the `args` array from inside a function, if you initialize it beforehand as described.

Comment: I find this much cleaner than iterating over the args.

Comment: This is simple and easy.  Great answer.   You posted this over 7 years ago, so hello from the future:  July 2017

Comment: Even better would be quoting like `echo "${args[0]} ${args[1]} ${args[2]}"`, or the arguments are subject to filename expansion.

Answer (score 24):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo name of script is $0
echo first argument is $1
echo second argument is $2
echo seventeenth argument is $17
echo number of arguments is $#
```

Edit: please see my comment on question

Answer (score 22):

Ravi's comment is essentially the answer. Functions take their own arguments. If you want them to be the same as the command-line arguments, you must pass them in. Otherwise, you're clearly calling a function without arguments.

That said, you could if you like store the command-line arguments in a global array to use within other functions:

```
my_function() {
    echo "stored arguments:"
    for arg in "${commandline_args[@]}"; do
        echo "    $arg"
    done
}

commandline_args=("$@")

my_function
```

You have to access the command-line arguments through the `commandline_args` variable, not `$@`, `$1`, `$2`, etc., but they're available. I'm unaware of any way to assign directly to the argument array, but if someone knows one, please enlighten me!

Also, note the way I've used and quoted `$@` - this is how you ensure special characters  (whitespace) don't get mucked up.

Answer (score 7):

```
# Save the script arguments
SCRIPT_NAME=$0
ARG_1=$1
ARGS_ALL=$*

function stuff {
  # use script args via the variables you saved
  # or the function args via $
  echo $0 $*
} 


# Call the function with arguments
stuff 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 4):

One can do it like this as well

```
#!/bin/bash
# script_name function_test.sh
function argument(){
for i in $@;do
    echo $i
done;
}
argument $@
```

Now call your script like

```
./function_test.sh argument1 argument2
```

Comment: `function print() {` is an amalgam between two different function declaration forms -- `function print {`, which is legacy ksh syntax that bash supports for backwards compatibility with pre-POSIX (which is to say, pre-1991) ksh, and `print() {`, which is POSIX-standardized. Consider using one or the other for wider compatibility with other shells; see also http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Answer (score 2):

This is @mcarifio response with several comments incorporated:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extdebug

function stuff() {
  local argIndex="${#BASH_ARGV[@]}"
  while [[ argIndex -gt 0 ]] ; do
    argIndex=$((argIndex - 1))
    echo -n "${BASH_ARGV[$argIndex]} "
  done
  echo
}

stuff
```

I want to highlight:

- The `shopt -s extdebug` is important. Without this the `BASH_ARGV` array will be empty unless you use it in **top level** part of the script (it means outside of the `stuff` function). Details here: [Why does the variable BASH_ARGV have a different value in a function, depending on whether it is used before calling the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69571809/why-does-the-variable-bash-argv-have-a-different-value-in-a-function-depending)
- `BASH_ARGV` is a stack so arguments are stored there in backward order. That's the reason why I decrement the index inside loop so we get arguments in the right order.
- Double quotes around the `${BASH_ARGV[@]}` and the `@` as an index instead of `*` are needed so arguments with spaces are handled properly. Details here: [bash arrays - what is difference between ${#array_name[*]} and ${#array_name[@]}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060447/bash-arrays-what-is-difference-between-array-name-and-array-name)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the shift keyword (operator?) to iterate through them.
Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
function print()
{
    while [ $# -gt 0 ]
    do
        echo "$1"
        shift 1
    done
}
print "$@"
```

Comment: `function print() {` is an amalgam between two different function declaration forms -- `function print {`, which is legacy ksh syntax that bash supports for backwards compatibility with pre-POSIX (which is to say, pre-1991) ksh, and `print() {`, which is POSIX-standardized. Consider using one or the other for wider compatibility with other shells; see also http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Answer (score 1):

I do it like this:

```
#! /bin/bash

ORIGARGS="$@"

function init(){   
  ORIGOPT= "- $ORIGARGS -" # tacs are for sed -E 
  echo "$ORIGOPT"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and likely the best way to get arguments passed from the command line to a particular function is to include the arguments directly in the function call.

```
# first you define your function 
function func_ImportantPrints() {
    printf '%s\n' "$1" 
    printf '%s\n' "$2" 
    printf '%s\n' "$3" 
} 
# then when you make your function call you do this:  
func_ImportantPrints "$@"
```

This is useful no matter if you are sending the arguments to main or some function like func_parseArguments (a function containing a case statement as seen in previous examples) or any function in the script.