# bash arrays - what is difference between ${#array_name[*]} and ${#array_name[@]}

Tags: arrays, bash

```
bash-3.00$ cat arr.bash  
#!/bin/bash  

declare -a myarray  
myarray[2]="two"  
myarray[5]="five"  

echo ${#myarray[*]}  
echo ${#myarray[@]}  

bash-3.00$ ./arr.bash  
2  
2
```

both are giving number of elements of array. So what is difference between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference. From the `bash` manpage:

> ${#name[subscript]}  expands  to  the 
>   length  of ${name[sub‐script]}.  If
>   subscript is * or @, the expansion is
>   the number of  elements  in the array.

Answer (score 7):

In this case, there is no difference. The two "all elements" subscripts make a difference when you expand the array and the expansion is surrounded by quotes.

`"${array[*]}` expands to `"two five"`

`"${array[@]}` expands to `"two" "five"` (i.e. *two* words).

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. They both give the number of elements in the array. The difference comes when you use the array expansion `"${array[*]}"` in double quotes and have IFS set to some value other than the default.

```
$ array=(1 2 3)
$ echo "${array[*]}"
1 2 3
$ saveIFS=$IFS
$ IFS=","
$ echo "${array[*]}"
1,2,3
$ IFS=$saveIFS
```