# Running venv Python script from PHP

Tags: php, python

I am running many python scripts from PHP. My php script template as below:

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");
header("Content-Type: application/json");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$command = escapeshellcmd("/usr/bin/python2.7 /path/to/script");
$args = escapeshellarg($_GET["title"]). " " . 
escapeshellarg($_GET["user"]);
$output = shell_exec($command . " " . $args);
echo $output;
```

But now I need to run some python scripts which are in virtual environment.

I tried to replace `/usr/bin/python2.7` with `./www/python/venv/bin/python3`, but it does not work.

So how to run it in PHP?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "but it does not work".

Comment: It means that Python script does not run.

Comment: Do you get an error? If yes, which one?

Answer (score 2):

To really run venv you would need to do three steps in the shell:

1. Change into project root.
2. source `venv/bin/activate`
3. run `python path/to/script`

Prerequisite you already have prepared a virtual env for the project.

You could combine this three steps into a bash script and call this script from PHP.

Comment: Yes, this method works but it does not take $args variable. Any suggestion, please?

Comment: I am sure you can access the $args variable in the bash script you call. However bash scripts are not my realm. Should be easy to look that up. Probably this is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740906/how-to-access-command-line-arguments-inside-a-function-using-bash

Comment: Figure out which part does not work! Can't you receive the argument inside the script? Does it work on the shell? Then, does it work from PHP?

Comment: Yes it perfectly works on shell, but does not in php. It seems that $args variable does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally You should use `APIs`, that is the best practice. But if you don't have `API` available you can use `pipe`. 
That can be used like this function: `exec_command($command)` where,
 `$command = $command . " " . $args`  
Below is the code:

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");
header("Content-Type: application/json");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$command = escapeshellcmd("/usr/bin/python2.7 /path/to/script");
$args = escapeshellarg($_GET["title"]). " " . 
escapeshellarg($_GET["user"]);

$command = $command . " " . $args;

$output = "";
$hd = popen($command, "r");
while(!feof($hd))
{
  $output .= fread($hd, 4096);
}
pclose($hd);

echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying this but it throws <class 'importError'>.

Comment: @Yethrosh, Please remove the function and use function's code directly.
And I'm sure enough that this <class 'importError'> is not because of this function exec_command() as I daily use this.

Comment: Could you please update the above code as you said? :)

Comment: @Yethrosh, Please try the updated solution, and if it helps you then accept the answer.

Comment: No, it does not goes in virtual environment.

Comment: @Yethrosh, Please post the exact error message you're getting when you run above code, so that I can change accordingly.

Comment: It throws error of importing python library which i installed only in virtual environment. And now I want to call python script (of virtual environment) using php as described in question. :)